# How can I make the right resolution to my kivy app?

Tags: kivy

I'm making an application on kivy and I want the size of the screen fit with my phone resolution
Can you please tell me how to do that , and if there is a simple solution like just add an argument to my code .
thank you very much in advance .

Comment: Could you explain what you did so far on that topic?

Comment: i'll send you my code right now

Comment: main.py
from random import randint
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import (NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty)
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp, sp
from kivy.uix.button import Button



class star(Widget):
    pass




class main1 (App):
    def build(self):
        return star()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main1().run()

Comment: main1.kv 
<star>:
    Image :
        source : "C:/Users/Mahdi Hadj Sassi/Desktop/images de kivy/a651b8a7955c.jpg"
        size : 700,700
        pos: self.pos
    smB :
        text : "-Start-"
        center_x: root.width / 2
        center_y: root.width / 3
        size : 120,50
        #back_color: .5, 0.5, .5, 1
        color : 1,1,0,1
        font_size : 25
    Label :
        text : "Topographe"
        font_size : 60
        color :1,1,0,1
        border : 1,1,0,1
        center_x: root.width / 2
        center_y: root.width / .8

Comment: Label :
        text : "(C) Hadj Sassi Mahdi"

        font_size : 10
        color :1,1,0,1
        center_x: root.width / 2
        center_y: root.width / 8

<smB@Button>:

    background_color : (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    back_color : (.5,0.5,0.5,1)
    border_radius : [18]
    canvas.before :
        Color :
            rgba : self.back_color
        RoundedRectangle:size : self.size
            pos : self.pos
            radius : self.border_radius